How to pick a 2D cross-sectional slice out of a 3D array at an angle, using scijs/ndarray?
I understand that using arr.pick() allows you to pick out a subarray along an orthogonal axis, however, how can I pick out an angled (non-orthogonal) slice?
slice = ndarray.pick(5, null, null);

how can i achieve something like this:
slice = ndarray.pick([5, null, null], angle);

I've tried looking at the other scijs libraries, but i could not find any utility function for this specific problem.
